# Remove command or/and other character from a text column in linux

Tags: linux, multiple-columns

How can I remove one or more characters from a specific text column in linux ?

Let's say I have have the following example.

```
sender | recipient | this is a , subject | qty
```

I would like to know how can I remove the "**comma**" only from the 3rd row.

Delimiter is "|".

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the easiest way.

```
$ a="sender | recipient | this is a , subject | qty"
$ var1=`echo $a | cut -d'|' -f3 `
$ var2=`echo $a | cut -d'|' -f3 | tr -d ','`
$ echo $a | sed "s/$var1/$var2/"
```

- after second line, var1 is the third column content
- after third line, var2 is the third column content without ','
  because we removed it with tr command
- finally replace var1 with var2